# Create empty data frame

Tags: r, matrix

I created a completely empty matrix. I would like to split a observation in 2 indices (like in Excel).

```
Indices <- matrix(NA, 8, 2)
rownames(Indices) <- rownames(Indices, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = "Plot")  # brauche ich das?
rownames(Indices) <- c("Plot 1", "Plot 2", "Plot 3", "Plot 8", "Plot 9", "Plot 10", 
                       "Plot 12", "Plot 13")
colnames(Indices) <- c("Density", "Trees per ha")
```

I would like to split `Density`one time in `Density only Oaks` and `Density total`. I have no idea how to call this, and is this even possible in R?

Comment: Can you show us what your desired output is?

Comment: Of course. The size of Plot 1 is 30*30 Meter, so with 10000/30*30 I calculate the density for 1 ha 
(Instead of calculating all trees on 1 full ha.)
`# Plot 1
# All
nrow(data[data$LOC==1, ])*(10000/(30*30))
# Oak
sum((data$Sp=="Quercus")&(data$LOC=="1"))*(10000/(30*30))`

So the result ist hat on Plot 1 I have a density of 600 Trees per ha, but only 300 Oaks.